# Matlab, values from get(bar(1))

Tags: matlab

let `h = bar(1)`. The output is then:`238.0096`. what does this value stands for ?

if I `use get(bar(1))`, none of the values matches `238.0096` ??

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you use

```
h=bar(1)
get(bar(1))
```

you create a new bar plot, which has totally new handles. Instead let's discuss this code:

```
h=bar(1)
get(h)
```

`h` is the handle to the bar series in your bar plot. When you call `get(h)`, you get a list of properties of the bar series. The bar series has no reference to itself, so the value of h is not listed.